React Native 0.74 Debugger
Has anyone upgraded to React Native 0.74. I need some advice on how to debug better. It's such a pain now. As the tools now suggested lack useful features. Is there any updated tools that allow me to view the following:

Console
Source
Redux
Network Tab
Async storage

As Flipper no longer works or the old react native debugger tool. I'm struggling to find information on debugging certain parts of my application. I can live without redux integration as I can use redux logger. But I feel the Network tab is a key feature and want to monitor the app's requests.
I have tried the experimental debugger RN has introduced but it lacks key features.

found this tool https://docs.infinite.red/reactotron/quick-start/react-native/#installing-reactotronapp
It works, its not perfect and you would have to use hermes devtools separately. But this sort of ticks my other boxes. Even though the UI is a bit messy. But might be an interim tool to use whilst we wait for something better.

For RN 0.73..0.75.2 (not for bridgeless mode)
Use https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger in conjunction with the 'react-native-devsettings' library, which allows you to use an external debugger.
Install react-native-debugger following the documentation.
Install react-native-devsettings in your project as a dev dependency:
npm install react-native-devsettings --save-dev
(yarn add react-native-devsettings --dev if you are using yarn)
Then, in the App.tsx (App.jsx) file, add at the top:
if (__DEV__) require('react-native-devsettings');
Run the project with the command npm run android.
Run the installed react-native-debugger.
In the emulator, press CTRL-M (CMD-M for Mac).
In the menu that appears, select Debug JS Remotely at the botom.

Additional informationb how to fix errors in the console -
https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/809
Enjoy your Debugging!
This debugger allows you to see Console, Source, Redux Store, Zustand Store, Network Requests, Apollo Requests, and AsyncStorage content.

In addition you can remove flipper debugger from the project to speed up compilation. https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1326#issuecomment-733031451

I thought react-native-debugger no longer worked with newer versions of react native eg +0.73, Will have to check it out again later

This is has it's own set of problems, updated libraries will not work with debugger, for example reanimated latest version will throw error if used when working with js debugger.

@KushagraAgarwal what you use mate for 0.74 then ? any ideas

@SidKaushik right now i am using a combination of debugging tools to make it work, hopefully will move to expo soon and will have less pain then

...I had more problems with the expo
